# Exclude URLs from maximum length on rejection reasons

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, suggested-edits, rejection-reasons

I just tried to reject a suggested edit with the following reason:

> This is a valid tag inside a question title. See also [Jon Skeet on writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

The  text box stated that this reason is by 36 characters too long:

[image]

However it takes the URL into account here, even if the resulting text would be much shorter because of the URL hidden behind a short link text.

**So here's my feature request:**
Please do not count URLs for the maximum length if they have a descriptive title (e.g. `[some short title](with a very very very long URL)`.

Maybe this also applies to comments, though that normally should be no problem, because comments can be much longer than rejection reasons.

Comment: I don't think the custom rejection text is parsed for MarkDown *at all*. There is *no point* in inserting a link in it, it's all displayed as plain text, IIRC.

Comment: There is a short URL for that very link: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints :p

Comment: I expect that this is constrained within the database...

Comment: @Bart didn't know that - thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't think the custom rejection text is parsed for MarkDown at all. There is no point in inserting a link in it, it's all displayed as plain text, IIRC. – [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140890/martijn-pieters) [15 mins ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168323/exclude-urls-from-maximum-length-on-rejection-reasons#comment495818_168323)

That's absolutely correct.

Comment: Thanks for clarification!